# The view for ItemsController::index() was not found

Tags: php, cakephp

I want print my name in cakephp 2, but i have error ' Error: The view for ItemsController::index() was not found.' , how can i fix problem?

my controller :

```
<?php

class ItemsController extends AppController {

public function index(){

    $this->set('data','waad');
}   
}
?>
```

my view/index.ctp :

```
<?php

echo $data 

?>
```

Comment: The error page should have told you where to create the missing view template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make an index.ctp file inside Templates/Items/
Here Items would be the folder corresponding to your ItemsController

You can easily bake templates, controllers and models in cakephp 3 by writing commands in your console like:

.\bin\cake bake controller ItemsController
.\bin\cake bake model Items
.\bin\cake bake template Items

Cakephp would bake everything for you!
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Good answer - some advice - place commands like ".\bin\cake bake model items" in code blocks for better readability.